# How can I get google ad sense to work with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, adsense

I'm trying to get google ad sense to work with my rails app and of course it more complex than it needs to be.

I made a partial for the ad code and then made a render tag that points to it.

_ads.html.erb

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Oped Ads -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567891234"
     data-ad-slot="123455667"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

show.html.erb

```
...
<p class="article-content"><%= @post.body.html_safe %></p>

        <%= render 'disqus' %>
        <br>
        <%= render 'ads' %> 
    </div>
```

Comment: That could be an issue with Turbolinks: See https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/issues/151 or http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/google_adsense.html If you are using Turbolinks.

Comment: @idmean What more could I tell you? Google seemed to make it pretty straight forward. It was pretty much copy and paste the code in the right place and done. if there's a file you want to see just let me know.

Comment: You don’t mention what exactly isn’t working. Is there just blank space instead of the ad? Does the ad load sometimes and sometimes not? Does the Google script not load (check the console)?

Comment: theres nothing there not even a blank space. I don't think its loading either. I don't know what exactly i should be looking for in the console though.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently set up Google's adsense not that long ago.

What I did was just like you created a partial I just put it in the a shared directory

this is how my file looks

```
#app/views/shared/_adsence.html.erb
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- default -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567891234"
     data-ad-slot="123455667"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

I hope that this helps